# Validate Bootstrap form w/ jQuery Validate BEFORE displaying modal w/button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons at the top of a jQuery validated form: one saves changes (the form's submit button), the other displays a TermsOfService dialog which when agreed will run some other code.

```
<button class="btn" value="Save Changes" 
        name="submit" type="submit" id="entryFormSave">Save changes</button>


<button class="btn" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        href="#modal-TOS" 
        data-backdrop="true" 
        data-keyboard="true" 
        id="entryFormSubmit">Submit for review</button>
```

The first/submit button validates the form - **I would love for the second button to validate the form also and if it passes validation, THEN display the TOS modal.**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I've tried a number of things, but none have worked. I noted that when adding the data-toggle="modal" it disables the button triggering the validation. The latest iteration was:
`$('#entryFormSubmit').click(function(){
        validate();
    });`

Any button I place in the form validates the form; however, once I add the data-toggle="modal" property, then the validation is disabled and I'm not enough of a JS maven to understand what to do next.

Comment: This is not a question. This is a code request.

Comment: I've updated the question with a snippet - the other pieces of code I've tried haven't worked, so pasting a jumble of spaghetti code isn't likely useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@frictionlesspauley - Thanks for even the small snippet.  I ended up back on the Jquery Validate page and found if I returned false - I interrupted the display of the modal, which is what was desired.

Here's what I used:

```
$("#entryFormSubmit").click(function() {
    var ValidStatus = $("#entryForm").valid();

    if (ValidStatus == false) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This code block is handing the validation checkup, but how can we add validation error messages at the top of corresponding form?

Answer (score 0):

call [.valid()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) on click :

```
  $(function(){
     $('#entryFormSubmit').on('click', function(){
         if($('#formid').valid()){
            //do whatever... call like calling $('formid').submit();
         }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but this didn't work for me.